# How can I mount a 9p filesystem from an unprivileged user namespace?

Tags: linux, mount, namespace, plan9

I'm trying to mount a 9p filesystem from inside a user namespace.

First, I run the 9p server:

`p9ufs -v --unix '/run/9p/srved'`

I then use the setuid binary 9mount (https://sqweek.net/code/9mount/) to mount it:

`9mount -u 'unix!/run/9p/srved' /tmp/ed1`

And it works.

I have edited 9mount's code to display its uid and euid, and it says:
"getuid returns 1000, and geteuid returns 0".
I also check with:
`grep Uid /proc/$(pgrep 9mount)/status` and get    `1000    0   0   0`.

Now, if I do the same thing from inside a user namespace, it fails.
First I enter the user namespace:
`unshare -U`

Then, from outside the namespace, I create a gid and uid mapping, because the doc says:

> if either the user or
> the group ID of the file has no mapping inside the namespace, the
> set-user-ID (set-group-ID) bit is silently ignored
>
> --   https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/user_namespaces.7.html

To create the mapping I run the following from outside the namespace:

```
sudo sh -c 'echo 0          0 4294967295 > /proc/11339/gid_map'
sudo sh -c 'echo 0          0 4294967295 > /proc/11339/uid_map'
```

Now, I run 9mount again, and it says "getuid returns 1000, and geteuid returns 0", and from outside the namespace, it is also seen as euid 0, YET, the call to mount() fails with "9mount: mount: Operation not permitted".

I don't understand.